# Queries running slower on production (failover cluster) than on homologation env

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, failover

I have a Windows Server 2012 cluster with two nodes running SQL Server 2012 for production and a Windows 2012 single server with SQL Server 2012 for homologation. I just restored the production database backup on homologation and tried some queries. The queries on production are taking longer to execute than on homologation environment.

This servers are all Hyper-V VMs, with 24GB RAM and two Intel Xeon 2.90GHz each. Why this different performance?

Is it possible to run a query on a specific node without changing the current active node in the failover manager?

---

UPDATE

Actually the servers are like this:

Dev:
2 Xeon E5-2667 (15M Cache, 2.90 GHz)
16GB RAM
SQL Server Min Memory: 4096
SQL Server Max Memory: 8192
Query Cost: 43,0161
Execution time: 16s

Homolog:
2 Xeon E5-2667 (15M Cache, 2.90 GHz)
16GB RAM
SQL Server Min Memory: 4096
SQL Server Max Memory: 8192
Query Cost: 42,6906
Execution time: 14s

Production (1 cluster manager and 2 nodes):
2 Xeon E5-2667 (15M Cache, 2.90 GHz)
24GB RAM
SQL Server Min Memory: 4096
SQL Server Max Memory: 16456
Query Cost: 45,5453
Execution time: 65s

Previously, the dev and production servers were using Min Memory = 0 and Max Memory = 2147483647, but it seems that changing the Max Memory didn't make any difference.

PS: I've executed the maintenance plan to rebuild the index and update the statistics after changing the Min and Max Memory.